# Copiar un valor de una columna en una nueva si una cierta columna contiene un elemento específico

Tags: pandas, dataframe, tablas

estoy haciendo un programa que lee dos dataframes, en uno de ellos tengo un formato de fechas tipo 2018-07-14, lo que quiero hacer es incluir los elementos de la columna Close2018-19 en una columna nueva con sus meses respectivos. Es decir, si en la columna de la fecha se muestra (2018-01-16), quisiera que su valor respectivo en la columna Close2018-19 se guardara en una columna llamada Enero2018-2019. Gracias de antemano, si no me estoy explicando bien puedo volver a redactar lo dicho, este es el código:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import copy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df=pd.read_csv('ETH-USD.csv')


df['Average-H-L'] = df[['High', 'Low']].mean(axis=1)
df = df[['Date','Close','Average-H-L']]

df2018 = df[(df['Date'].str.contains("2018-"))]
df2018.columns = ['Date','Close2018','Average-H-L2018']
df2019 = df[(df['Date'].str.contains("2019-"))]
df2019.columns = ['Date','Close2019','Average-H-L2019']

df2 = pd.concat([df2018,df2019], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
df2['Close'] = df2[['Close2018', 'Close2019']].mean(axis=1)
df2['Average-H-L'] = df2[['Average-H-L2018', 'Average-H-L2019']].mean(axis=1)
df2 = df2[['Date','Close','Average-H-L']]
df2.columns = ['Date','Close2018-19','Average-H-L2018-19']

df2['Year'] = df2['Date'].str.split('-').str[0]


df2['January2018-2019']= df2['Date'].str.contains("-07-")

#result = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1).corr()
#result
df2
```

Y la tabla actual de cómo se muestra es la siguiente:
[image: Tabla de resultado con el código actual]

Comment: Buen día, ¿Puedes agregar los datos de tu CSV? Podría ser a través de un URL o si por lo menos copias y pegas 10 líneas (5 que tengan la fecha de enero 2018 y 5 que sea otra fecha) para poder reproducir tu problema y ayudarte a encontrar la solución

Comment: Lo pude encontrar aquí, espero que sirva: https://www.kaggle.com/varpit94/ethereum-data

Comment: Disculpa, ¿Pudiste encontrar una solución?

Comment: Buen día, no lo he intentado porque no has agregado los datos a tu pregunta, en el URL que enviaste me pide registrarme para bajar los datos. No es necesario poner todas las filas, copia y pega unas cuantas para que podamos utilizar la información. Saludos!

Comment: No te preocupes, pude encontrar una solución :) utilicé el siguiente código: ```df2 = df[['Date','Close2018-19']]
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])
df2['month'] = df['Date'].dt.month_name()

df2 = pd.pivot_table(df2, index='Date', columns='month', values='Close2018-19', fill_value=0)

df2.columns = [f'{m}2018-2019' for m in df2.columns]``` ¡Saludos!

Comment: Te invito a escribir una respuesta con tu solución y aceptarla, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude encontrar una solución:
Usé la función "pivot_table" para fijarme en los meses dentro de las fechas. Para esto, también tuve que convertir las fechas con el formato pd.to_datetime y hacer una columna con los meses.

```
df2 = df[['Date','Close2018-19']] 
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date']) 
df2['month'] = df['Date'].dt.month_name()  
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df2, index='Date', columns='month', values='Close2018-19', fill_value=0)  
df2.columns = [f'{m}2018-2019' for m in df2.columns]
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).